# Find and append dates in multiple columns based on a date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a way to find dates in multiple columns that fall within the past week and output those dates. Goal is to make it expandable through many more columns.

We will assume the week is 1-Sep through 7-Sep
EX:

| Name | Box 1 | Box 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bill | 1-Sep-21 | 3-Sep-21 |
| Bob | 30-Aug-21 | 3-Sep-21 |
| Jeff | 31-Aug-21 | 4-Sep-21 |
| Sam | 31-Aug-21 | 29-Aug-21 |

**Output**

| Name | Item Sold | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bill | Box 1 | 1-Sep-21 |
| Bill | Box 2 | 3-Sep-21 |
| Bob | Box 2 | 3-Sep-21 |
| Jeff | Box 2 | 4-Sep-21 |

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check [ask] - and show us what you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to unpivot the date columns using Power Query and then apply a date filter to the result.

The coding in the advanced query editor would look something like:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Name"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", each [Value] >= #datetime(2021, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0) and [Value] <= #datetime(2021, 9, 7, 0, 0, 0))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

By using unpivot other columns, you'd be able to add as many date columns to the original table as you like.